# how to print hyphen in double quotes along with other strings

Tags: shell-script, text-formatting, echo, printf

```
 cat inv_summary_1.txt  | while read -r aLine
do
    F1=`echo "$aLine" | cut -d "," -f1`
    F2=`echo "$aLine" | cut -d "," -f2`
    echo   " 0 RUN_ID  STR [0] \"${F2}\" "
done
```

> 191245204696,REG-00000000001

i have a file inv_summary_1.txt above   with delimiter as "," want to print second field  along with predefined values

> 0 RUN_ID      STR [0]

191245204696,REG-00000000001

i want to get out put as

> 0 RUN_ID      STR [0] "REG-00000000001"

but what i am getting is

> " RUN_ID      STR [0] "REG-00000000001

double quotes are not proper 
even first 2 characters in echo statement are also missing.

please help , i believe "-" has some significance in Unix shell script, please help

> Note : i am using Linux 4.1.12-94.3.9.el7uek.x86_64 #2 SMP Fri Jul 14
>   20:09:40 PDT 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: I missed the part where you're printing a hyphen in double-quotes; did you mean "the hyphenated field #2"?

Comment: i was referring to any variable which contains special character -

Answer (score 2):

Consider parsing the text with a dedicated tool instead of a shell; `awk` is one way:

```
awk -F, '{print "0 RUN_ID STR [0] \""$2"\""}' < input
```

Results in this output:

```
0 RUN_ID STR [0] "REG-00000000001"
```

Comment: awk -F, '{print "0 RUN_ID STR [0] \""$2"\""}' < inv_summary_1.txt                      
 " RUN_ID STR [0] "REG-00000000001 getting same error

Comment: It's hard to tell with the formatting, but it looks like you may have copy/pasted the command incorrectly. Please try again and if you still get an error, paste the command and the error into an edit of your question. Thank you!